# Django - interact Bokeh scripts with Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, bokeh

I deployed app to Heroku. Everything works, except creating plots with Bokeh. Plots are created based on user's input, but plots are not displayed. After inspecting network I can see:

[image]

in my **base.html** I have:

```
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

The full code you can see on my github: https://github.com/f4lco0n/git-efforts. Is there any way to get this scripts to heroku?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this, but this helped me out a bunch when I had to integrate bokeh with django. https://hackernoon.com/integrating-bokeh-visualisations-into-django-projects-a1c01a16b67a

Comment: @Reez0 I dont have problem with displaying it on localhost, but after deploying on Heroku app can't get this libraries